# Any issues using constructor functions as custom React Hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm playing around with the use of constructor functions in a React application. However, I have never seen anyone discuss this usage before, so I'm wondering if there's a problem with it that I'm not aware of.

I have a constructor function called `NameSection` that is serving like a React hook. It has its own state (first and last name of a person) that it manages. I use it in my `PersonalInfo` component to render one of two things: either the current first/last name or inputs for the two fields so that they may be edited.

One reason I'm using a constructor function is because I'm considering turning it into an interface that can be inherited from. Then, I can later implement a `PasswordSection`, `EmailSection`, etc that need to follow a similar structure.

From my tests so far, I haven't seen any issues with using a constructor function in this particular context. But I'd like to hear others' thoughts on this. Are there any problems with this sort of implementation in the world of React?

In PersonalInfo.js

```
const PersonalInfo = ({info}) => {
    const nameSection = new NameSection({firstName: info.firstName, lastName: info.lastName});

    return ( 
         <SettingsChild heading={"Name"} onSaveAttempt={nameSection.nameExitEdit} onEdit={nameSection.nameEnterEdit}  disableSave={nameSection.isNameSectionError()}>
              {nameSection.renderNameSection()}
         </SettingsChild>
    )
}

export default PersonalInfo;
```

In NameSection.js

```
function NameSection({firstName, lastName}) {
    const initialNameSection = {
        editMode: false,
        firstName: {input: firstName, error: ""},
        lastName: {input: lastName, error: ""}
    }

    const [ data, setData ] = useState(initialNameSection);

    const handleNameChange = (event) => {
        const key = event.target.name;
        const value = event.target.value;
        setData(prev => ({
            ...prev,
            [key]: {input: value, error: ""}
        }))
    }

    this.isNameSectionError = () => (!data.firstName.input || !data.lastName.input);

    this.nameEnterEdit = () => {
        setData(prev => ({
            ...prev,
            editMode: true
        }))
    }
    this.nameExitEdit = () => {
        if (this.isNameSectionError()) {
            if (!data.firstName.input) {
                setData(prev => ({
                    ...prev,
                    firstName: {...prev.firstName, error: inputErrors.requiredField}
                }))
            }
            if (!data.lastName.input) {
                setData(prev => ({
                    ...prev,
                    lastName: {...prev.lastName, error: inputErrors.requiredField}
                }))
            }
        }
        else {
            setData(prev => ({
                ...prev,
                editMode: false
            }))
        }
    }

    this.renderNameSection = () => {
        return (
            data.editMode ? 
                <React.Fragment>
                    <TextBox label={"First name"} name={"firstName"} value={data.firstName.input} onChange={handleNameChange} errorMessage={data.firstName.error}/>
                    <TextBox label={"Last name"} name={"lastName"} value={data.lastName.input} onChange={handleNameChange} errorMessage={data.lastName.error}/>
                </React.Fragment>
                :
                <p>{`${data.firstName.input} ${data.lastName.input}`}</p>
        )
    }
    
}

export default NameSection;
```

Comment: Seems to me a new `nameSection` variable would be instantiated each render cycle. React hooks are also only valid in functional components and other react hooks. `NameSection` is neither of these, but I think the linter is viewing it as a react component since the signature matches. I don't think this will work as you want it to.

Comment: each file is a separate module. what do you gain by putting all of the functions in a class?

Comment: @DrewReese From what I've seen, using a constructor function works fine. I haven't bumped into any issues. Also, hooks can be used inside of regular functions. The React website has a page about creating custom hooks using a function: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html. It's just that it's not a constructor. Thanks for pointing on that `nameSection` would be instantiated on each render. But is that any different from how the custom hooks in the link I provided behave? They would also be called on each render.

Comment: @Thankyou I'm building account settings for a webpage, so there will be other settings that need to be displayed/edited, like password, address, email, etc. These sections all need to follow a similar format and therefore implement similar functions. So I'd like to create an abstraction from `nameSection`. I'd have an interface (maybe call it `Section`), which would require functions like `enterEdit`, `exitEdit`, `handleChange` to be implemented by child classes like `NameSection`. I think this will help make the account settings code more organized.

Comment: False. I guess you didn't understand the latter part of my comment where I said the linter ***must*** be viewing your `NameSection` function as a react component and thus it is, falsely, being validated as correct hook usage. Please review the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html). Yes, it *is* different than the react framework internally tracking the same hook being called each render. In this case each render is a new "object" and there is no "rerender".

Comment: Based on your other comment I feel you are also missing the [Composition vs Inheritance](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html) aspect of React.